# HTTP requests assign multiple values to a key in params

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests

I am using python's requests library to do a 'GET' from an API. here is part of my code :

```
payload = { 'topicIds':'128487',
            'topicIds':'128485', 
        'topicIds': '242793',
            'timePeriod':'10d', }

r= requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
```

According to the API documentation, we can assign multiple topicIds to one request like this: `<url>topicId=123&topicId=246`

when i try to set topicIds value as a list like this:

```
payload = { 'topicIds':['128487' , '242793'],
```

I get an error : `{u'error': u'topicIds: has 2 terms, should be between 0 and 1'}`

However when i run the code, i only get data from the last topicIds =>  'topicIds': '242793'
Am i writing the payload dictionary wrongly?

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a reason you are not doing a list of topicIds?

Comment: yep, it didnt work (please see edits)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
payload = {'topicIds[]': ['128487', '242793']}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
```

This is the most common way of defining arrays in query strings.

Comment: how does this fit into the payload variable?

Comment: That was just an error on my part when copy pasting my test code. I have edited it now. The thing to notice is the brackets after topicIds. It's worth a try, and we really can't help anymore without knowing the API specification.

Comment: @fasouto edited my answer for some weird reason without testing at all, so I rolled it back. The resulting url is NOT the same with and without brackets. With brackets results in http://example.com/?topicIds%5B%5D=128487&topicIds%5B%5D=242793 - Without results in http://example.com/?topicIds=128487&topicIds=242793 - Brackets is the most common way to define arrays in query and post parameters (PHP parses GET params as arrays with this syntax for example).

Comment: @scandinavian_ I tested and it didn't work for me this is why I edited it. I saw topicIds=[1,2] and topicIds=1&topicIds=2 but never topicIds[]=[1,2] so I tough it was a typo. I don't know whats the best way and I don't have time to investigate now so apologies for the inconvenience

Answer (score 3):

This would work as well

```
params = {'topicIds': ['128487', '128485', '242793'],
         'timePeriod':'10d', }

r= requests.get(url, params=params)
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes you are writing payload wrongly, just try to print this dict, you will get

```
{'topicIds': '242793', 'timePeriod': '10d'}
```

The keys are overridden in dictionary

I think that it would be better, to make one string out of all topicIds, something like that

```
'<separator>'.join([<list of topicIds>])
```